# is there a value in this answer?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, specific-answer

I fail to see any value in [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/157660). Do I miss something?

Question:

> I have to make database for data that are currently being kept in excel files, so I have to do some changes before writing into database. I'm going to read those files in java, and write them from java into db. Should I use hibernate for that job? Or how else to connect those read data in java, with database?

Answer (full text):

> **LibreOffice and OpenOffice could scale you to the moon. Headless linux-Mac-win. You can get the contents of spreadsheet with licenses cost and about 200 lines of code.**

Comment: Wow.  What a crap answer for a poor question to begin with.  Gnat, you should be commended for salvaging anything out of that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the poster of the answer might be suggesting using the OpenOffice.org (or LibreOffice) APIs to open the spreadsheet files, access the data, perform the transformations, and then write the proper data into the new database. Although it's not a very good explanation, I don't see how it's not an answer.

Comment: what a relief - thanks Thomas! Details you provided make much better sense. I [clarified the answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/157660/revisions "answer revisions history") with these details - and revoked my downvote along the way :)

Comment: @gnat I'm rolling back that edit since I have no evidence to support my claim. That's how I'm interpreting the post - if you want more detail, leave a comment asking for more details. Don't put my words into someone else's post.

Comment: unrelated - while I have your attention, would you mind taking a look at the question about migration from _Unix and Linux_ hanging there in chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5453695#5453695

Comment: @gnat - I didn't see a notification of that ping...odd. I'll look at it, yes. Thanks.

Comment: I see - left comment as you suggested (the undownvote also has been rolled back)

Comment: Wow...that is a horrible "answer". It really doesn't address the question at all. It mentions 0% of the question which is related with what to do with the data once you read it and how to map it to the database.